# I can't connect to Mac with Xamarin Mac Agent from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm continuing my adventure with Xamarin.

I'm developing an Xamarin Forms application with a Portable Class Libraries (PCL).

I have compiled and debugged my application by Android, but now, I'm interested to run the application in iOS to test in this platform.

I have a problem with the connection between my PC and the Mac.

I have a PC (Windows 10) with Visual Studio Community 2017 with Xamarin tools installed.

In my Mac Mini, I have installed OS X (v10.8.5)

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/giheh.png)

Comment: You have to install Visual Studio for Mac on your Mac.

Comment: visual studio is not installed in my mac

Comment: Read my comment again.

Comment: i need version for os x version 10.8.5

Comment: You need to update the version of Mac OS then. Visual Studio for Mac needs 10.12 or above.

Comment: Please read this documentation: [https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/) more carefully.